# Property value could not be read when using @RefreshScope in spring controller

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud, spring-boot-actuator

I am writing 2 applications using **cloud config**, one the server and another is the client. The server is running on 8888 and holding the configuration stored in GIT repository. It has the property:

> spring.cloud.config.server.git.uri=${HOME}/Desktop/config-repo

The client is using the above configuration where it has one property as: message. Client is a restful webservice which has a controller as:

```
@RestController
class Controller{

    @Value ("${message}")
    private String message;

    @Value ("${course}")
    private String course;

    @RequestMapping("/showMessage")
    private String showMessage(){
        return message;
    }

    @RequestMapping("/showCourse")
    private String showCourse(){
        return course;
    }
}
```

When accessing **http://localhost:8080/showCourse** it is perfectly working and showing the message in the web page which is configured in the message.properties.

---

### **Issue when using @RefreshScope**

Now when I am using **@RefreshScope** with the controller, I am not at all getting any output where the webpage is blank. When debugging, the issue is with

```
@Value ("${message}")
private String message;

@RequestMapping("/showMessage")
private String showMessage(){
    return message;
}
```

in the controller where the message is null.

This happens when using the annotation - RefreshScope.

I have added the code/project at GIT: https://github.com/santoshkar/SpringBootCentralConfigUsingGit.git

Kindly help.

Thanks,
Santosh

Comment: can you add `@EnableAutoConfiguration` on your controller class and try it again.

Comment: thanks, Adding @EnableAutoConfiguration didn't help.

Comment: ok. do you have this two dependencies? `<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-context</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.2.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-autoconfigure</artifactId>
  <version>1.4.1.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>`

Comment: I added, still no luck :(

Comment: @santu Specify the git URI location in bootstrap.properties instead of application.properties.Always specify cloud-config properties in bootstrap.properties instead of application.properties.Technically, bootstrap.properties is loaded by a parent Spring ApplicationContext. That parent ApplicationContext is loaded before the one that uses application.properties.

Comment: We haven't started support for spring boot 2.0.

Comment: Came across the same issue, do u solve it and how?